# How to make a image collab with fade responsive on phones?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website, where I want to`­`have 3 photos in the top fade in and out.

The problem  I'm currently dealing with is the phone version, and some weird black box appearing.

codepen link : https://codepen.io/audn/pen/xLOZeW

Comment: https://codepen.io/audn/pen/xLOZeW

Comment: your provided codepen's code is not valid. Could you check [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjZNKY) out

Comment: This is where the code is: https://rocketprices.net/giveaways @Zico

Comment: So, If you think the problem is caused by a mobile phone, it would be nice to know what kind of phone it is and what browser you are using. And what code are you using? And where does the black box appear? Please edit your question and include all required information. _Questions without a clear problem definition tend to get closed._

Comment: @ventiseis 
I added code, something that should be  enough.

Comment: Phone  users itself, iphone, safari, samsung etc

Comment: @audun As noted for example [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289731/are-we-actually-forbidden-from-linking-to-external-tools-such-as-codepen-jsfiddl), it is required to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.